# Error in deserialising WCF json object C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, winforms, wcf

I have developed an application (C# MVC web and C# Desktop application) that communicates with database using WCF service.

It’s currently hosted at several locations, and is working fine. Except at one location, I’m facing issue with deserialisation of JSON object in one of the service method, only when calling through desktop application.

> Error getting When deserialization  : “There was an error
>   deserializing the object of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Namespace.ModelClassName, Namespace,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]. Encountered
>   unexpected character ':'.”

- Deserialize Method Currently Using:

Try

```
   var url = BaseServiceURL + "wsModel.svc/ ModelDynamicSearch " + "/" + ModelID.ToString() + "/" + SearchText.ToString() + "/" + SearchType.ToString();

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            List<ModelName> lstVisitors = new List<ModelName>();

    var t = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ModelName>));

            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                lstVisitors = (List<ModelName>)t.ReadObject(responseStream);
            }
```

Catch

```
Error Getting
```

Finally

- Service Contact:

  ```
   [OperationContract]

   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "ModelDynamicSearch/{ModelID}/{SearchText}/{SearchType}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

      List<ModelName> ModelDynamicSearch(string ModelID, string SearchText, string SearchType);
  ```

  Model Definition:

  ```
  public class ModelName

  {

      [DataMember]
      public int ModelID { get; set; }

      [DataMember]
      public int ModelCompanyID { get; set; }

      [DataMember]
      public string ModelName { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Comment: Does you "ModelName" class has the DataContract attribute? You can try to deserialize the stream using an encoding, see this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, DataContract attribute worked and is working fine now.